# Importing python file from other directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a following directory structure:

```
                                parentDirectory
                                       |
                   -----------------------------------------
                  |                                         |
                 Task                                    Configs
                   - pythonFile1.py                         - Config1.py
                                                            - Config2.py
```

The Configuration files have few configuration constants defined inside a class.

Now, I want to import the configuration files from Configs directory into the python file under Tasks directory and make use of constants defined inside the class in each config file.

I had tried with adding(after reading through few answers) -

```
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/MyName/parentDirectory/Tasks')
```

inside the config files.

Since I am new to python, I don't know to what extent I am correct in adding the above lines.

Please help!

Comment: It may be interesting to look at the [*package* chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in Python tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it backward: if you want your "Tasks" to be able to import your "Configs", you need to add code to the Tasks to insert the Configs path into `sys.path`.

Comment: Adding the line to "Tasks" throws an error saying-     Importerror: No module named Config1

Comment: OK.  Now imagine what I am thinking when you say "it throws an error."  How can I help you?  What other information must I need?